# Nginx: redirect non-www https to https://www

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect

I'm having some issues when trying to redirect `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`. It simple gives me a redirect loop.

This is my site's nginx configuration I had prior to the changes I made, which is located at /etc/nginx/sites-available.

Can somebody tell me how to implement the redirection correctly using this configuration altered with the new redirection directives.

```
server {

listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

root /var/www/example.com/public_html;
index index.php;
server_name example.com www.example.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to remove `example.com` from the `server_name` directive of your main `server` block.

Second, you need to listen for `https` connections in the `server` block that performs the redirection.

For example:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name www.example.com;

    ...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did exactly how you have mentioned but still it keeps me in the redirecting loop. It just redirects between https://example.com and https://www.example.com without stopping. Are we missing something?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache? Did you notice that your return statement was also changed?

Comment: Yes, I cleared my cache also. I'm using wordpress. I changed my site url to use www but still it throws me through the loop. Return statements are 'HTTP/2 200' for https://www and HTTP/2 301 for https without www.

Comment: Ignore the comment above. Now everything works perfectly. Thank you!!!